# How to work out Chartjs using TypeScript with Chartjs.definitelyTyped from github

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, chart.js

I want to use Chartjs(chartjs.org) as my charting tool along with AngularJS using TypeScript. I have installed DefinitelyTyped for Chartjs from GitHub to incorporate creation of Chartjs charts in my TypeScript written controller. I can't find any related questions on doing this thing.

I just need to know how we populate data to our charts using DefinitelyTyped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find example usages of `chart.d.ts` in the form of a tests file right next to the [definition in the `DefinitelyTyped` repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chart.js/chart.js-tests.ts).

Comment: indeed, types are part of chat.js now, no need to install `@types/chart.js`

Answer (score 3):

A bit outdated question, but had similar request since I'm working with Angular + PrimeNG (which uses `chart.js`) with npm for packages.

Just install types from

```bash
npm i --save-dev @types/chart.js
```

and then use it for example:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

…

const myOptions: Chart.ChartOptions = {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'My title',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
};
```

Might help someone.

Comment: This is wrong, you are using Chart.js V3, in V3 the types are build in while @types/chart.js has the types for V2 which will collide

Comment: Well, not sure about types compatibility (of course you should not use types for ver. 2.x with 3.x chart.js..) but this is working fine with version 2.9.4 which I'm using, also there is no specified version in question.

Comment: How this works with V4? I added  `/// <reference path="node_modules/chart.js/dist/types/index.d.ts" />` but no intellisense.