# Pass component variable to JS library in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a dashboard component with shows charts on the page. The charts library needs data in order to render the chart and display on dashboard. Currently the data is static and works fine, but i need the data to be given by typescript variable which will be initialized by API call.

**Dashboard HTML:**

```
        <div class="panel panel-white">
          <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Series Chart</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <canvas id="series-chart"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Dashboard Component:**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  totalSymbol = 0;
  chartLabels = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private apiUrl: ApiUrlService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchTotalSymbol();
  }

  fetchTotalSymbol() {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl.getBaseUrl() + 'symbol/count').subscribe(data => {
      this.totalSymbol = +data;
    });
  }

}
```

**dashboard.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  "use strict";
  new Chart(document.getElementById("series-chart"),
    {
      "type": "doughnut",
      "data": {
        "labels": ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
        "datasets": [{
          "label": "My First Dataset",
          "data": [300, 50, 100],
          "backgroundColor": ["rgb(236, 94, 105)", "rgb(0, 112, 224)", "rgb(241, 194, 5)"]
        }]
      }
    });

});
```

I need to replace Labels Red,Blue,Yellow in `dashboard.js` to A,B,C from dashboard component `chartLabels` after API call `fetchTotalSymbol()`.

I am including dashboard.js in `.angular-cli.json` under `scripts` array.

Comment: `new Chart(document.getElementById("series-chart"),` you are doing it wrong. Use refs, nativeElement, but never DOM directly. Post component annotations and how dashboard.js is included.

Comment: Why do you use separate dashboard.js? It should be possible to integrate it into angular typescript code

Comment: @piotrgajow how can integrate it in typescript code?

Comment: @dfsq can i get link to any blog where i can study that.

Comment: If I understand correctly that you are using `Chart.js` library, you could have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885809/how-to-work-out-chartjs-using-typescript-with-chartjs-definitelytyped-from-githu or this example https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chart.js/chart.js-tests.ts